# Freeze when playing URL with 'audioplayers' library in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have a list of URLs that I want to play with 'audioplayers' in Flutter. When the URL list starts to play, the freezing process occurs after playing 7-8 URLs. App and page freezes. This is always shown as an error:

```
E/flutter (11570): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed
E/flutter (11570): #0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:35:31)
E/flutter (11570): #1      AudioPlayer._completePrepared.<anonymous closure> (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:292:29)
E/flutter (11570): #2      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
E/flutter (11570): #3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (11570): #4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (11570): #5      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (11570): #6      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
E/flutter (11570): #7      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
E/flutter (11570): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (11570): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (11570): #10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (11570): #11     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:195:12)
E/flutter (11570): #12     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
E/flutter (11570): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (11570): #14     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
E/flutter (11570): #15     _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
E/flutter (11570): #16     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
E/flutter (11570): #17     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (11570): #18     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

My related codes are as follows:

```
  bool isPlaying = false;
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  int currentIndex = 0;
  int start = 0;
...
//button pressed
 onPressed: () {
        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
        if (start == 0) {
          start++;
          playAudioInstructions();
        } else if (start == 1) {
          start++;
          audioPlayer.pause();
        } else {
          start--;
          audioPlayer.resume();
        }
        setState(() {});
      },

...

void playAudioInstructions() {
    playAudio(urlList, currentIndex);
  }

Future<void> playAudio(List<String> urlList, int currentIndex) async {
    await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(urlList[currentIndex]));
    audioPlayer.onPlayerComplete.listen((event) {
      if (currentIndex < urlList.length - 1) {
        audioPlayer.stop();
        currentIndex++;
        playAudio(urlList, currentIndex);
      } else {
        currentIndex = 0;
        audioPlayer.stop();
        start = 0;
      }
    });
  }
...
```

I couldn't figure out the cause of the freezing. I'd be happy to get help with the code snippet.